# Is this a bug? (recursive constructors in Java)

Tags: java, recursion, constructor

I've been playing with recursive constructors in Java. The following class is accepted by the compiler two examples of recursive constructors in Java. It crashes with a StackOverflowError at runtime using java 1.7.0_25 and Eclipse Juno (Version: Juno Service Release 2 Build id: 20130225-0426).

```
  class MyList<X> {
    public X hd;
    public MyList<X> tl;

    public MyList(){
      this.hd = null;
      this.tl = new MyList<X>();
    }
  }
```

The error message makes sense, but I'm wondering if the compiler should catch it. A counterexample might be a list of integers with a constructor that takes an int as an argument and sets `this.tl` to null if the argument is less than zero. This seems reasonable to allow in the same way that recursive methods are allowed, but on the other hand I think constructors ought to terminate. Should a constructor be allowed to call itself?

So I'm asking a higher authority before submitting a Java bug report.

EDIT: I'm advocating for a simple check, like prohibiting a constructor from calling itself or whatever the Java developers did to address https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-1229458. A wilder solution would be to check that the arguments to recursive constructor calls are decreasing with respect to some well-founded relation, but the point of the question is not "should Java determine whether all constructors terminate?" but rather "should Java use a stronger heuristic when compiling constructors?".

Comment: It is not a compiler bug to create an infinite recursion, inside or outside a constructor.

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-1229458

Comment: That part of the JLS is referring to a constructor calling `this(...)` recursively, not instantiating another object.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't see any reason why a constructor should more need to terminate than any other kind of function. But, as with any other kind of function, the compiler [cannot infer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) in the general case whether such function ever terminates (halting problem).

Now whether there's generally much need for a recursive constructor is debatable, but it certainly is not a bug, unless the Java specification would explicitly state that recursive constructor calls must result in an error.

And finally, it's important to differentiate between recursive calls to constructor(s) of the *same* object, which is a common pattern for instance to overcome the lack of default parameters, and calling the constructor of the same class to create *another* object, as done in your example.

Answer (score 3):

You could even have several constructors with different parameters, calling each other wiht `this(...)`. In general, by computer science, a termination of code can not always be guaranteed. Some intelligence, like in this simple case, would be nice to have, but one may not require a compiler error. *A bit like unreachable code.* There is no difference between a constructor or normal method in my eyes however.

Comment: In your opinion, should the Java language try to give a compiler error?

Comment: @ben He's just said it's impossible. So has everybody else so far.

Comment: As @ben points out, in the particular case of `this(...)` the JLS (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.8.7) does preclude a constructor from invoking itself recursively. I think this is actually detectable since the call to `this(...)` must be the first in a constructor, can't be part of conditional logic, and there can only be so many constructors defined.

Answer (score 1):

Although this specific situation seems quite obvious, determining whether or not code terminates is an impossible question to answer.

If you try to configure compiler warnings for infinite recursion, you run into [the Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem):

> "Given a description of an arbitrary computer program, decide whether
> the program finishes running or continues to run forever."
>
> Alan Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve the
> halting problem for all possible program-input pairs cannot exist.